# how can I stop animation at the last frame for few seconds

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to  stop an animation at the last frame, and after that after few seconds it will call another animation .. if anybody has a tutorial, then please give it to me.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code of what you have already and specify which bit is giving you trouble.

Comment: I use this code http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I solved my problem through Nstimer and stopping animation